# Remove/Don't show empty node in D3 Force Layout / Force Simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes, force-layout

i have a similar question to this one: [d3.js V3 force directed graph and unlinked nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134424/d3-js-v3-force-directed-graph-and-unlinked-nodes/46135974#46135974) but the solution there did not help me.

My csv dataset has some empty sources and targets
my csv looks like this: (sorry this is not the real data , because it's much larger, but I hope this will do it)

```
John,
,Alex
Alice,Bob
Eve,Carol
Dave,Bob
Charlie,
```

so what I get is John, Alex and Charlie connected via an "empty" node. What I want is them wihtout any connection to any other node. Just a single node.
Here's my code snippet:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink())
        .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.8))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.8))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
        .force("collide",d3.forceCollide().radius(d => d.r * 10))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100));


d3.csv("myData.csv", function(error, links) {
            if (error) throw error;

            var nodesByName = {}

            links.forEach(function(link) {
                link.source = nodesByName[link.source] || (nodesByName[link.source] = {name: link.source});
                link.target = nodesByName[link.target] || (nodesByName[link.target] = {name: link.target});  
            }); 

 var nodes = d3.values(nodesByName);

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .on("mouseover", tooltipOn)
            .on("mouseout", tooltipOff)

            simulation
                .nodes(nodes)
                .on("tick", tick)
                .force("link").links(links);

function tick() {
                link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
            }
```

(I tried it with d3.v3 force layout and d3.v4 force simulation with the same result)

Thanks for any help (and sorry for any mistakes - english is not my first language and this is my first question here)

Comment: The solution from the linked question should fix your problem. Did you try anything?

Comment: No, as stated in the first line of my question, I have already tried the suggested solution there

Comment: Could you try to filter out the data you don't like? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922236/removing-rows-when-reading-data-d3/12922313

Comment: Can you show **why** that other question does not solve your problem, or, how you changed your code to adopt the proposed solution? Like suggest by @Mehdi, I am pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow, by the way. The expectation is that you show what you have tried, and we take it from here. [These guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) should be followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by:

- storing nodes based on the source and target values, only when the value is not and empty string
- storing links only when both the source and the target are not empty.

Rather than removing records from the parsed CSV dataset, a new `links` array can be populated based on the presence of source and target.

Functional demo in the snippet below

```js
let csv = 'source,target\nJohn,\n,Alex\nAlice,Bob\nEve,Carol\nDave,Bob\nCharlie,'
 , input = d3.csvParse(csv)
 , nodesByName = {}
 , links = []

input.forEach(function(link) {

 if (link.source)
    // source is not empty, record node
  nodesByName[link.source] = {name: link.source}
  
 if (link.target)
    // target is not empty, record node
  nodesByName[link.target] = {name: link.target}
  
 if (link.source && link.target)
    // both source and target are not empty, record link
  links.push({
   source: nodesByName[link.source]
   , target: nodesByName[link.target]
  })
})

console.log('-------------')
console.log('nodes')
console.log(nodesByName)

console.log('-------------')
console.log('links')
console.log(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-dsv/1.0.8/d3-dsv.min.js"></script>
```